# how to select sql row between 3 table, in 2 table should have given value but 1 table should not value

Tags: mysql, select

I'va 3 table 1 named `job_order` col name
`id, job_code, Job_name, weight, material, etc`

2nd table named `material_issued` col name
`id, job_code, material, date, etc`

3rd table named `productions` col name
`id, job_code, produced, etc`.

how can i select `job_order` which not entered in `productions` but should be enterd in both `job_order` and `material_issued`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM job_order
WHERE job_code IN (SELECT DISTINCT job_code from material_issued)
AND job_code NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT job_code from productions)
```